# Publishing failed in tomcat after package change

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a simple web application which was working fine when I had default package. when I added package & moved the classes to them, the deployment fails with error :

```
The servlets named [FileUploadDBServlet] and [com.db.FileUploadDBServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/FileUploadDBServlet] which is not permitted
```

I tried deleting the old project & creating a new one. But somehow the old reference still exists. How can I remove the old references.

I am using Java 7, Tomcat 8 & eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help.

I identified the solution for the problem.

In web.xml, both `servlet-class` and `servlet-name` should be fully qualified like :

```
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>FileUploadDBServlet</servlet-name>
**<servlet-class>com.db.FileUploadDBServlet</servlet-class>**
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
**<servlet-name>com.db.FileUploadDBServlet</servlet-name>**
<url-pattern>/FileUploadDBServlet</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entry of your old project from server.xml
or delete old server with its folder and create new one then restart your eclipse.

I hope it will help you..!